# Google Analytics ID web/mobile app exchange possible?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, web-applications, ios

If I have a website with Google Analytics ID UA-xxxx, and now I want to develop an iOS app related to my site, can I use the same id UA-xxxx or do I have to create a new ad-hoc one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better to separate your unique id, that way you can measure performance separately. You can always count the iOS app results toward your overall, but at least you don't have to filter through to see how the app is doing.